# Android TableLayout Column span/stretch to fit children ( TextView ) length

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a TableLayout, and a fixed number of columns (=4), and the task is to fit a list of 
TextView into the TableLayout. The problem is, since the text can be of arbitrary length, I have specified column span according to the text length. So let's assume that for each 3 character I will need another extra column span (e.g. word "my" will occupy 1 column, and "love" will require span to 2 column)

Now let's assume my list of text is "I" "will" "programmatically" "show"...
the layout would be like:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| I |  will |   |
+---+---+---+---+
|programmatically|
+---------------+
```

because the third word "programmatically" is too long to fit to the remaining column in row 1, I will have to put it to the next row (not a problem).

My question is, now row 1 only has two items, and there will be empty space left, is there 
a convenient way to "auto fit" the items so that they will occupied the whole row?  how would it work, since items can be of different span values? or this has to be done programmatically? (no pun intended)

my tableLayout xml is just an empty table definition, with rows and items created dynamically in code:

```
<TableLayout
  android:id="@+id/table"  
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:stretchColumns="*"
  />
```

A concrete [screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5wrk.jpg), the white space is what I want to get rid of

Comment: What do you mean by "auto fit" to occupy whole row??  maybe explain with example..

Comment: sorry, was editing that table example...

Comment: Do you mean to say `I` and `will` will stretch to fill entire row, instead of leaving empty space on the right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want

Comment: You should simply have `weight=1` for each column. If you post your code, how you create rows and items, maybe I can post exactly how to do it. But basic idea is each item in the row has `weight=1`

Comment: thanks, added a screenshot link (can't add image yet.) will try the weigh first!